# The point of a group-theoretic Chinese Remainder Theorem?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

It states that

> for coprime $m,n$ nonzero integers, $C_{mn} \cong C_m \times C_n$.

However, I know a theorem that says

> Cyclic groups with the same order are isomorphic. So $C_{mn} \cong C_m \times C_n$.

Uhm, so what's the point of having $m,n$ being coprime? Even if they're not, don't $C_{mn}$ and $C_m \times C_n$  have the same order and thereby, the second theorem says that they are isomorphic anyway? I don't know if they are referring to diffrent things and if so, why.

Answer (score 5):

If $m$ and $n$ are not coprime, then $C_m\times C_n$ will not be cyclic: the order of the group $C_m\times C_n$ is $mn$, but if $(a,b)$ is any element of $C_m\times C_n$ then the order of $(a,b)$ is the least common multiple of the orders of $a$ and $b$, which will be strictly less than $mn$ if $m$ and $n$ have a common factor.

Answer (score 2):

$C_m\times C_n$ isn't cyclic if $m$ and $n$ aren't coprime. For instance, $C_2\times C_2$ has no element of order $4$.

Comment: thanks! I thnk i got it now